# Using date as calender week in chart

Tags: c#, charts

I would like to use dates as calendar weeks for x-value of a chart. I calculate the calendar week for the given date and get the week as an integer. This works fine. Problem is when a new year starts the week 1 already exist.

[image]

I would like to have e.g. 01/2017.

Comment: Well, '01/2017' isn't an integer. If you're stuck with using integers, think about starting with the year, as 201701. The leading zero on the week makes this sort correctly when it's used as a string.

Comment: or group by years and take the weeknumber + (year difference) so you end up with week1,2,3,4,....52,53,54....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, '01/2017' isn't an integer.

If you're stuck with using integers, think about starting with the year, as 201701. The leading zero on the week makes this sort correctly when it's used as a string.

My personal preference is to either use a string, or use client-side software that can format dates for output. I find the format '2017-01' easiest to read.

FWIW, I've *never* seen a situation in which the week number alone was sufficient. Sooner or later, you *always* need the year.